# Is there a way to keep hierarchical clustering order constant across groups for correlation matrices?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, correlation, hierarchical-clustering

I have created multiple correlational matrices for age ranges (e.g. 1-5, 5-10, 10-15 years old). However, when I do hierarchical clustering using ggcorrplot for example, running ggcorrplot(corr_age_1_mat, hc.order = TRUE) for plotting, the clustering order obviously changes if I do this separately per correlational matrix. Is there a way to keep to a standard order across plots while still employing some sort of clustering? Or perhaps adhering to one select "best" order?

For instance, the image below:

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly would you define the "best" ordering?